# How to remove a variable from child script environment in lua?

Tags: lua, love2d, lua-5.1

I have a script which I load with `loadfile` and then run it. Also I have the variable `love` in the scope of parent lua script and I want this variable be `nil` inside the child script enivornment but everything else untouched (`print`, `math`, `pairs`, all the std lib of Lua). How can I do that?

This does not work:

```
local scenario = love.filesystem.load(script)
local env = {}
setmetatable(env, { __index = _G })
env.love = nil
env.game = Game
setfenv(scenario, env)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work because `env` inherits from `_G` and so `env.love` is resolved in `_G`. Setting `env.love = nil` does not add a `love` entry to `env`.

Set `env.love = false` or `env.love = {}`.

Comment: Why setting it to `nil` does not add it?

Comment: Setting to `nil` removes an entry in a table.

Comment: but it does not - the child script still can use `love` in it's scope.

Comment: `env.love` is already `nil` *before* the line `env.love = nil` executes, so that line doesn't do anything. When you access `env.love`, the `__index` metamethod is invoked precisely *because* the true value of `env.love` is `nil`; this is exactly the behavior which the manual specifies.

Answer (score 2):

```
local scenario = love.filesystem.load(script)
local env = setmetatable({}, { __index = 
   function(t, k)
      if k == "love" then
         return nil
      else
         return _G[k]
      end
   end
})
setfenv(scenario, env)
```

Comment: Note that `setfenv` [was removed in Lua 5.2](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.2).

Comment: @ComicSansMS - This question is about Lua 5.1, as the author uses this function in his code (look also previous question of this author).

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Agreed, I just added the comment in case someone stumbles across this question in the future and wonders why your answer doesn't work for them.

Comment: @ComicSansMS - I've added "Lua 5.1" tag to the question to avoid possible misunderstanding (actually, this question is about Love2D working over Lua5.1)